# Scanning processes... takes ages on my pc (10+ minutes). How stop that?

Tags: apt

Scanning processes...  takes ages on my pc (10+ minutes). How stop it from doing this?

This happen every time that I call apt remove, apt purge or apt install and related commands.

Is it safe to press ctrl+C?

```
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.4-2) ...
(Ανάγνωση βάσης δεδομένων ... 565371 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for docker-ce (5:20.10.12~3-0~debian-bullseye) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
Scanning processes...                                                                  
Scanning candidates...  [================================================                                   ] (10+ minutes takes)
```

Comment: How about some context. When does this appear? After what commands or actions? Your question could use some more details.

Comment: `sudo apt-get --purge remove os-prober` removed that process.

Comment: I do not believe it is safe to CTRL+C when running apt. There are many reasons why. One is the lockfile. There are other reasons that I can think of but I'd have to look into them to be sure.

Comment: Ηλία, when posting command output here, please run with `LC_ALL=C` to get the messages in English. For example, `LC_ALL=C sudo apt-get --purge remove os-prober`.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get --purge remove os-prober` removed that process. Thankfully!

Comment: Pretty sure it was a bad idea  to kill that off.

Comment: @David It's complicated. On most systems, it's only used on the initial installation. It becomes a problem if you decide to install an additional OS to your system. If it's a linux based OS, the new install should have the updated OS list and bootloader (e.g. grub or lilo). On newer versions of Ubuntu (22.04) os-prober is actually disabled in Grub by default and must be enabled for it to work. I guess that, if you need to use it in the future, you could always reinstall it and uninstall it after updating Grub.